# Chinese is garbled in settings page when using Template10

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, template10

I am writing a UWP app using Template10 (Hamburger Template), when I customize the settings page, I find the Chinese characters are garbled.

Partial code of `SettingsPage.xaml`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="SplictFictionSettings" 
           Text="文件分割设置"
           Margin="12"
           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"/>
<TextBox x:Name="RegularChapterSavePathTextBox"
         Text="{Binding RegularChapterSavePath}"
         Margin="12"
         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
         RelativePanel.Below="SplictFictionSettings"/>
<Button x:Name="ChooseRegularChpterSavePath"
        Content="打开"
        Margin="12"
        RelativePanel.RightOf="RegularChapterSavePathTextBox"
        RelativePanel.Below="SplictFictionSettings"/>
```

After builded, I get unreadable characters.
[Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AN2d.png)

Other pages I added myself works fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry I am not an UWP guy. However, as multi-language developer in some apps. Your issue is that your editor supports both UTF-8 and UTF-16 charsets, but your code (app) doesn't.

the question mark shows on unsupported charsets in any languages.  Make sure your Chinese string is indeed in the UTF-8 (not BIG-5 or GB).

Comment: Did as you said, I solved the problem by changing the source code encoding to UTF-8. Thank you so much!